# Where is the 2.0 play binary when compiling from source?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I compiled playframework 2.0 from the latest git commit, but can't find the play binary. Where is it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When compiling using `./build` normally it should be in the root folder of play.

Comment: Ah, I think I was searchingi nside the 'framework' directory I had to launch ./build from. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure either ;) But when you execute `./package` instead of `./build`, you'll get a zip of the build.